# Show that a subspace of $\ell^2$ is not complete

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, proof-verification, hilbert-spaces, banach-spaces

I would like to know if this exercise is correct.

Let $\Bbb R^\infty=\{x:\Bbb N\rightarrow \Bbb R: \exists n \text{ such that}\quad x(k)=0 \quad \forall k\geq n\}$. Show that $(\Bbb R^\infty, \| \cdot\|_{l^2})$ is not complete.

Let $x\in l^2$ be such that $x(k)= ({1\over 2})^k$. Let $(x_n)_n$ a sequence in $\Bbb R^\infty$ defined as: $$x_n(k)= \begin{cases} ({1\over 2})^k, & \mbox{if } k\leq n \\ 0 & \mbox{else }\end{cases}.$$
If we show that $x_n\rightarrow x$ in $l^2$ we've done, since $x\notin \Bbb R^\infty$.

So, $$x(k)-x_n(k)= \begin{cases} 0, & \mbox{if } k\leq n \\({1\over 2})^k  & \mbox{if }k\geq n+1 \end{cases}$$ for each $n\in \Bbb N$.

Now, $\|x-x_n\|_{l^2}^2=\sum_{k=1}^\infty|x(k)-x_n(k)|^2=\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty ({1\over 2})^{2k} $, for each $n\in \Bbb N$.

Thus $\lim_{n\to \infty} \|x-x_n\|_{l^2}^2=\lim_{n \to \infty}\sum_{k=n+1}^\infty ({1\over 2})^{2k}=0.$ Since $x_n\rightarrow x$ in $l^2$, $(\Bbb R^\infty, \| \cdot\|_{l^2})$ is not complete.

Comment: Yes, it's correct. I could however imagine correctors that would like to see an argument supporting that the limit in the end is zero. This of course follows directly from the definition of convergent series.

Comment: You're right, in fact my problem is that I'm not so sure how to prove that the limit is zero. Could you tell me how I have to do?

Comment: The limit of the rest sums converging to zero is by definition the same as the series converging. For this specific series, you can show convergence using the usual criteria for series convergence, like the quotient criterion, or you can simply compute the rest sums explicitly.

Comment: This space have countable basis so by corollary of Baire category theorem it is not complete

Answer (score 4):

Your proof is correct. But with almost no extra work you can prove a better result: considered as a subset of $\ell^2$, the space $\mathbb R^\infty$ is *dense*. (Consequently, not closed, hence not complete in the $l^2$ metric.)

The proof goes just as yours, but without specifying $x$. Just let $x$ be any element of $l^2$, then define 
$$x_n(k)= \begin{cases} x(k)  & \mbox{if } k\leq n \\ 0 & \mbox{else }\end{cases}$$
Observe that 
$$
\|x-x_n\|^2 = \sum_{k>n} |x(k)|^2
$$
which converges to zero, being the tail of a convergent series.